# Link lists that share common elements

Tags: python, networkx, connected-components

I have an issue similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements) with a few differences/complications

I have a list of groups containing members, rather than merging the groups that share members I need to preserve the groupings and create a new set of edges based on which groups have members in common, and do so conditionally based on attributes of the groups

The source data looks like this:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| Group ID | Group Type | Member ID |
+----------+------------+-----------+
| A        | Type 1     |         1 |
| A        | Type 1     |         2 |
| B        | Type 1     |         2 |
| B        | Type 1     |         3 |
| C        | Type 1     |         3 |
| C        | Type 1     |         4 |
| D        | Type 2     |         4 |
| D        | Type 2     |         5 |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

Desired output is this:

```
+----------+-----------------+
| Group ID | Linked Group ID |
+----------+-----------------+
| A        | B               |
| B        | C               |
+----------+-----------------+
```

A is linked to B because it shares 2 in common
B is linked to C because it shares 3 in common
C is *not* linked to D, it has a member in common but is of a different type

The number of shared members doesn't matter for my purposes, a single member in common means they're linked

The output is being used as the edges of a graph, so if the output is a graph that fits the rules that's fine

The source dataset is large (hundreds of millions of rows), so performance is a consideration

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200969/how-to-group-all-labels-index-which-shares-at-least-one-1-in-the-same-column?noredirect=1&lq=1) poses a similar question, however I'm new to Python and can't figure out how to get the source data to a point where I can use the answer, or work in the additional requirement of the group type matching

Comment: Hi, welcome on SO. A similar question of your sugestion uses a different concept of connected components. According to your requirements B should not be connected with E (unlikely to answer suggested), isn't it? Also are Group Type and Member ID sorted?

Comment: Thank you, lots of time here getting tips, but really stumped this time! There's no E in the example, and there would be no pattern if that's what you mean? Group type and member ID could be sorted at source if that were to help

Comment: I mean that one of solutions in links you mentioned should be a good example that your problem is not equivalent to finding of connected components (especially, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200969/how-to-group-all-labels-index-which-shares-at-least-one-1-in-the-same-column?noredirect=1&lq=1). In one of the answers components `[A, C]` and `[B, D, E]` are found but `B` and `E` is not a suitable pair you would like to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some thing like this-

```
df1=df.groupby(['Group Type','Member ID'])['Group ID'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
df2=df1[df1['Group ID'].str.contains(",")]
```

This might not handle the case of cyclic grouping.

Comment: I was able to use this to get what needed, looks like I was overthinking it! Many thanks Sushant

Comment: You are most welcome SquirreledHogs, Good to see it helped.

Comment: This seems, however, quite a challenging task if not using that comma trick with pandas