# vertex contraction - python

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, vertex

I have a subgraph with some connected components as follows:

[image]

I'm using

```
bicomponents = list(nx.biconnected_components(T))
```

to identify all the connected components in the subgraph. I need to remove the whole connected component and contract that component to a vertex and get a new leaf. For example, I need to remove the component `{28,30,31}` and introduce a new vertex `51` (I have `n= 50` vertices, so new one will be `51`) and join with `29` to get a new leaf.

Can someone help me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To contract the biconnected components, we will first relabel the nodes in each component so that they have the same label, then remove the self-loops.

## Construct the label mapping

```
label_mapping = {}
for idx, node_component in enumerate(filter(lambda s: len(s) > 2, nx.biconnected_components(g)), start=len(g) + 1):
    for node in node_component:
        if node not in label_mapping:
            label_mapping[node] = idx
```

Here I made two assumptions: We discard trivial biconnected components (hence the `filter`, which can be easily removed if undesired), and if a node belongs to two biconnected components (cut vertex), we don't contract these two components into a single node, but keep two nodes for two components. If this is not the desired behaviour, we need to merge the components having a common node, whose solution is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements).

## Contract the components

```
h = nx.relabel_nodes(g, label_mapping)
h.remove_edges_from(h.selfloop_edges())
```