# Merge and remove same key python

Tags: python, merge, key, python-3.6

I have this:

```
 a = [['huhu', 'dow'], ['haha', 'dow'], ['haha', 'pow'], ['haha', 'dow'],  ['haha', 'mat'], ['hihi', 'dow'], ['hihi', 'pow']]
```

and I want

> [['huhu', 'dow'], ['haha', 'dow', 'pow', 'dow', 'mat'], ['hihi',
>   'dow'], ['hihi', 'pow']]

Comment: why `['hihi', 'dow'], ['hihi', 'pow']` and not `['hihi', 'dow', 'pow']`? + Why not use a dictionary? Looks like you are dealing with *keys*..

Comment: What's the logic behind your expected output? Also, please add your code that you've tried so far. SO is not a homework solving service. People here can help you when they know that you've already tried to solve your problem by yourself and for any reason you couldn't.

Comment: Can you explain why the last two entries of your dictionary aren't combined? Seems to break your pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge lists that share common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a dictionary here, it is much cleaner. In particular I would recommend a [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dct = defaultdict(list)

for key, *values in a:
    dct[key].extend(values)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'huhu': ['dow'],
             'haha': ['dow', 'pow', 'dow', 'mat'],
             'hihi': ['dow', 'pow']})
```

If you want this as a list, it is a fairly simple comprehension:

```
[[k, *v] for k, v in dct.items()]

# [['huhu', 'dow'], ['haha', 'dow', 'pow', 'dow', 'mat'], ['hihi', 'dow', 'pow']]
```

Comment: and if OP for some reason insists on the output, he can use `res = [[k] + v for k, v in dct.items()]`.