# Combine lists with common elements

Tags: python, list, networkx

Say I have for example the following nested list:

```
L = [['John','Sayyed'], ['John' , 'Simon'] ,['bush','trump'],
     ['Sam','Suri','NewYork'],['Suri','Orlando','Canada']]
```

How can I group these sublists, by getting the union of sublists which have a common element with at least another sublist within the group? So for the previous example, the result should be:

```
[['John','Sayyed','Simon'] ,['bush','trump'],
 ['Sam','Suri','NewYork','Orlando','Canada']]
```

Thus, the first two sublists are joined as they share `'John'`.
Could someone please share their valuable thoughts?

Answer (score 25):

In many cases, modeling a problem as a graph, can make make fairly complicated tasks much easier. In this case, what we'd be looking for from a graph theory point of view,  are the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of the graph.

So a simple way to go about this, is to generate a graph with [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/), and add your list as the graph edges using [`add_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edges_from.html). Then use [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html), which will precisely give you a list of sets of the connected components in the graph:

```
import networkx as nx 

L = [['John','Sayyed'], ['John' , 'Simon'] ,['bush','trump']]

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(L)
list(nx.connected_components(G))

[{'John', 'Sayyed', 'Simon'}, {'bush', 'trump'}]
```

---

#### What about sublists with multiple (>2) items?

In the case of having sublists with more than `2` elements, you can *add them as paths* instead of nodes using `nx.add_path`, since they can connect multiple nodes:

```
L = [['John','Sayyed'], ['John' , 'Simon'] ,['bush','trump'],
     ['Sam','Suri','NewYork'],['Suri','Orlando','Canada']]

G=nx.Graph()
for l in L:
    nx.add_path(G, l)
list(nx.connected_components(G))

[{'John', 'Sayyed', 'Simon'},
 {'bush', 'trump'},
 {'Canada', 'NewYork', 'Orlando', 'Sam', 'Suri'}]
```

We can also vivisualize these connected components with [`nx.draw`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html):

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=20, k=2/np.sqrt(G.order()))
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='lightgreen', node_size=1000, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

---

#### On connected components (graph theory)

More detailed explanation on [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)):

> In graph theory, a connected component (or just component) of an undirected graph is a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the supergraph

So essentially, this code creates a graph, with edges from the list, where each edge is composed by two values `u,v` where `u` and `v` will be nodes connected by this edge.

And hence, the union of sublists with at least one sublist with a common element can be translated into a Graph Theory problem as all nodes that are reachable between each other through the existing paths.

Comment: Interesting approach, please explain what this does

Comment: What happens if the sub-list have more than two elements?

Comment: @Aiyaz updated with a more generic case of having sublists with more than 2 elements

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach

```
L = [['John','Sayyed'], [ 'John' , 'Simon'] ,['bush','trump']]
L[0].extend([x for x in L[1] if x not in L[0]])
L.pop(1)
print(L)
```

See

[List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

[Append vs Extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `connected_components` in `networkx`:

```
import networkx as nx 
​
L = [['John','Sayyed'], ['John' , 'Simon'] ,['bush','trump'],
     ['Sam','Suri','NewYork'],['Suri','Orlando','Canada']]
​
G = nx.Graph()
​
for i in L:
    G.add_path(i)
​
lst = list(nx.connected_components(G))
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'John', 'Sayyed', 'Simon'},
 {'bush', 'trump'},
 {'Canada', 'NewYork', 'Orlando', 'Sam', 'Suri'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If order *is* important and the list are large, you can use this two pronged method:

```
 l = [['john', 'sayyid'], ['john', 'simon'], ['b', 't']]

 def join(l1, l2):
     mset = set(l1)
     result = l1[:] # deep copy
     for each in l2:
         if each in mset:
             continue
         else:
             result.append(each)
     return result
```

To merge within the master list, you can just call the list by their rank and pop the original list:

```
l1 = l.pop(0)
l2 = l.pop(0)
l.insert(0, join(l1, l2))
>>> l:
[['john', 'sayyid', 'simon'], ['b', 't']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge 2 lists:

```
merge = lambda l1, l2: l1 + [ x for x in l2 if x not in l1 ]
```

To be more efficient, create a `set` on `l1`;

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the nested list looks like the following

```
L = [['John','Sayyed'],['John','Simon'],['bush','trump'],['Sam','Suri','NewYork'],['Suri','Orlando','Canada']]
```

Below I will share two potential options to solve OP's problem.

---

**Option 1**

Using (the comments make it self-explanatory):

```
L = [set(l) for l in L] # Convert the list of lists to a list of sets
for i in range(len(L)): # For each set
    for j in range(i+1,len(L)): # For each set after the current set
        if len(L[i].intersection(L[j])) > 0: # If the two sets have a common element
            L[i] = L[i].union(L[j]) # Union the two sets
            L[j] = set() # Empty the second set
L = [list(l) for l in L if len(l) > 0] # Remove empty sets and convert the list of sets to a list of lists
```

Which will give us

```
[['John', 'Sayyed', 'Simon'], ['bush', 'trump'], ['NewYork', 'Sam', 'Canada', 'Suri', 'Orlando']]
```

For the sake of convenience, one might want to refactor it

```
def union(L):
    L = [set(l) for l in L] # Convert the list of lists to a list of sets
    for i in range(len(L)): # For each set
        for j in range(i+1,len(L)): # For each set after the current set
            if len(L[i].intersection(L[j])) > 0: # If the two sets have a common element
                L[i] = L[i].union(L[j]) # Union the two sets
                L[j] = set() # Empty the second set
    L = [list(l) for l in L if len(l) > 0] # Remove empty sets and convert the list of sets to a list of lists
    return L
```

And then simply

```
L_new = union(L)

[Out]: [['John', 'Sayyed', 'Simon'], ['bush', 'trump'], ['NewYork', 'Sam', 'Canada', 'Suri', 'Orlando']]
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`NetworkX`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html).

One starts by creating an empty graph with no nodes and no edges.

```
G = nx.Graph()
```

Then, in order to add the nodes, there are various options, such as using [`Graph.add_nodes_from`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html) and [`Graph.add_edge`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html)

```
for l in L: # For each sublist
    G.add_nodes_from(l) # Add all the elements of the sublist as nodes
    for i in range(len(l)): # For each element in the sublist
        for j in range(i+1,len(l)): # For each element after the current element
            G.add_edge(l[i],l[j]) # Add an edge between the two elements

# or

for l in L: # For each sublist
    G.add_nodes_from(l) # Add all nodes in the sublist to the graph
    for i in range(len(l)-1): # For each node in the sublist
        G.add_edge(l[i],l[i+1]) # Add an edge between the current node and the next node in the sublist
```

Then, finally, one can get a list of the connected components with [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html)

```
L = list(nx.connected_components(G))

[Out]: [{'John', 'Sayyed', 'Simon'}, {'bush', 'trump'}, {'NewYork', 'Sam', 'Canada', 'Suri', 'Orlando'}]
```

As an additional step, one might want to plot the graphs. For that, [`NetworkX`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) provides basic functionality for visualizing graphs. [See here more information on drawing graphs with `NetworkX`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html).

One approach would be with `matplotlib`.

There are various layouts one can use, such as:

- [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html)

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  # Create the layout for the graph
  pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.5, iterations=20, scale=10)

  # Draw the graph with the layout
  nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', font_color='white', node_size=2500, node_color='blue')

  # Show the plot
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]
- [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html)

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  # Create the layout for the graph
  pos = nx.spiral_layout(G, scale=5)

  # Draw the graph with the layout
  nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', font_color='white', node_size=2500, node_color='blue')

  # Show the plot
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]
- [`shell_layout`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.shell_layout.html)

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  # Create the layout for the graph
  pos = nx.shell_layout(G, scale=10)

  # Draw the graph with the layout
  nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', font_color='white', node_size=2500, node_color='blue')

  # Show the plot
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image]
- and more, depending on one's use case and goal. [See here all the available layouts](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout).