# Group sublists with common elements

Tags: python, list, networkx

Im struggling with something that is probably not complicated. I have a list of lists and I want to Group the elements together if they share any common elements:

[image]

For example first list [1,2] is grouped with third list [3,4] because they "overlap" through second list [2,3]

There must be some easier way than:

```
a = [[1,2],
     [2,3],
     [3,4],
     [7,8]]

newlist = []
for count, pair in enumerate(a):
    if count==0:
        newlist.append(pair)
    else:
        for index, group in enumerate(newlist):
            if not set(group).isdisjoint(pair):
                newlist[index].extend(pair)
            else:
                newlist.append(pair)

newlist = [set(group) for group in newlist]

newlist
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {8, 7}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886179/9698684) post, a way to approach this is using `networkx`. Generate a graph, and add your list as the graph edges using [`add_edges_from`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edges_from.html). Then use [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html), which will precisely give you a list of sets of the connected components in the graph:

```
L = [[1,2],
     [2,3],
     [3,4],
     [7,8]]

import networkx as nx

G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(L)
newlist  = list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

---

```
print(new_list)
# [{1, 2, 3, 4}, {7, 8}]
```

Comment: Nice! What if each list in the list of lists had 100 elements? Would using networkx still be possible?

Comment: Check how I approach this in the [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886120/union-of-sublists-with-common-elements), it is possible! @BERA