# Explode command not working while calling excel or csv file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, pandas-explode

i have been working with this explode command. please here is my code fyr.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:/Users/nick/Documents/Python') # NOTE csv_filepath
df= pd.read_excel('output1.xlsx', usecols=['PartNumber', 'RefList'], index_col=False)
print(df.explode('RefList'))
file_name ='output2.xlsx'
df.to_excel(file_name)
```

**Input file data // output1.xlsx**

| PartNumber | RefList |
| --- | --- |
| ram | apple,orange |
| ravi | banan,pinapple |

**receiving output data // output2.xlsx** "same" i don't know where iam making a mistake.

| PartNumber | RefList |
| --- | --- |
| ram | apple,orange |
| ravi | banan,pinapple |

if I try to work with this below code it works

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  df = pd.DataFrame({'animals': [['koala', 'kangaroo', 'echidna'], 
                           ['sloth', 'alpaca'], 
                           ['zebra', 'lion', 'baboon']],
               'diet': [['herbivorous', 'herbivorous', 'carnivorous'], 
                        ['omnivorous', 'herbivorous'], 
                        ['herbivorous', 'carnivorous', 'omnivorous']],
               'country': ['Australia', 'Peru', 'Kenya']})
                print`(df)`
```

I have work with explode command not working.
try to compile it with .data frame it works fine.
if i call a excel or csv file not working.

Comment: pandas functions do not inplace as default. use following code : `df.explode('RefList').to_excel(file_name)`

Comment: **df.explode('RefList').to_excel('output1.xlsx')
print (df)
file_name ='output2.xlsx'
df.to_excel(file_name)
df.explode('RefList').to_excel(file_name)
print(df)** reciving same output

Comment: To use explode, **you need to convert value to a list,** like your below example. I replied as such.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'PartNumber': ['ram', 'ravi'], 'RefList': ['apple,orange', 'banan,pinapple']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df:

```
    PartNumber  RefList
0   ram         apple,orange
1   ravi        banan,pinapple
```

**Code**

```
df.assign(RefList=df['RefList'].str.split(',')).explode('RefList')
```

output:

```
PartNumber  RefList
0   ram     apple
0   ram     orange
1   ravi    banan
1   ravi    pinapple
```

then use following code

```
file_name ='output2.xlsx'
df.assign(RefList=df['RefList'].str.split(',')).explode('RefList').to_excel(file_name)
```

Comment: the above mention code repeat same output table i don't know why. i like to share my answer it works but i don't know the above mention method all the prefeed a easy way why doesn't work for me. thank you i post my code if anyone spot error kindly notify me.

Comment: @NICK_CS It is because it is not a list. The explode function is for splitting lists, not comma. provide `df.to_dict()` to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:/Users/nick/Documents/Python') # NOTE csv_filepath
df1= pd.read_excel('output1.xlsx', usecols=['PartNumber', 'RefList'])


df2 = df1['RefList'].str.split(' ',expand=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

df2 = df3.melt(id_vars=['PartNumber', 'RefList'])#, var_name='df.columns.values')
 
df2.explode ('RefList')

file_name='output2.xlsx'

df2.to_excel(file_name)
```

output table #

| PartNumber | RefList | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ram | apple orange | 0 | apple |
| ravi | banan pinapple | 0 | banan |
| ram | apple orange | 1 | orange |
| ravi | banan pinapple | 1 | pinapple |

Comment: just provide `df1.to_dict()`

Comment: Hash_Value   Name  ID
0              [8a43]   abcl   1
1        [79e2, b183]   abc2   2
2              [f82a]   abc3   3
3              [b183]   abc4   2
4  [eaa7, 5ea9, 1cee]   abc5   4
5              [5ea9]   abc6   4
6        [1cee, 26ea]   abc7   4
7              [79e2]   abc8   2
8              [8a43]   abc9   1
9              [26ea]  abc10   4  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421152/how-to-explode-pandas-dataframe-with-lists-to-label-the-ones-in-the-same-row-wit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421152/how-to-explode-pandas-dataframe-with-lists-to-label-the-ones-in-the-same-row-wit only Hash_Value (explode)

Comment: This is really no problem. All the problems have already been solved, but you just don't know it. so just provide `df1.to_dict()` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['RefList'] = df['RefList'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')

print(df.explode('RefList'))
```

output #

```
   | PartNumber |  RefList |
   |------------|----------|
  |  ram   |  apple  |
  |  ram   | orange  |
  | ravi   |  banan  |
  | ravi | pinapple  |
```