# How to find matches in a set of lists?

Tags: python

Suppose my input is a list of lists:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 6], [1, 4], [3, 8]]
```

I need to get matches in the output, but not all in one list.
For example, 1 lies in the list `[1, 2]` and also in the list `[1, 4]`. I want to get `[1, 2, 4]` and the same for 3.

That is, the result should be something like:

```
(1, 2, 4)
(3, 6, 8)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Would a dictionary work better?  e.g {1:[2,4],3:[6,8]} ?  The number you are looking for always the first on in the lists in your example. what should this function return for f(2)?

Comment: You only want to match two elements of a list at a time and they can't be merged with other elements, right? like 0th n 1th index , then 2nd n 3rd index

Comment: "Is it possible?" If you can describe the criteria clearly, you should be able to write a program that implements it. So of course it's possible.

Comment: they can't be merged with other elements - that's correct.

Comment: In each list there is 2 elements always. but each element can be repeated in different lists unlimited times

Comment: Do you control the function that is building the original list of lists?  Can you change that function to write to a dictionary each time rather than (or as well as) to a list of lists?

Comment: @DarkKitsune you only want to merge two consecutive elements, right? What will be the desired output of this [[1,2],[1,4],[1,2],[1,2]]?

Comment: @JeffUK yes, i can use dictionary i think. 

now i try:
list_of_lists = [[1,2], [1,4], [3,8], [9,3]]
a = [set(l) for l in list_of_lists]

b = a[0] 
c = a[0] 
for s in a[1:]:
    b = b.union(s)
    c = c.symmetric_difference(s)

result = b.difference(c)
print (result);

but this way i get repetitions in one line. I need not to mix them.(

Comment: @LakshikaParihar for [[1,2], [1,4], [1,2], [1,2]] it should be [1,2,4]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge lists that share common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution using the list_of_list

```
lists =  [[1, 2], [3, 6], [1, 4], [3, 8]]
indx = [0]*len(lists)
final=[]
for i in lists:
    temp =[]
    for k in range(len(lists)):
        if i[0] in lists[k] and indx[k]==0:
            indx[k] = 1
            temp+=lists[k]
    if len(temp)>0:
        final.append(set(temp))
print(final)
```

The output of the above code will be `[{1, 2, 4}, {8, 3, 6}]`

- I created a list that keeps track of the elements already used
- then I am checking the 0th index of every element of the list if it's not already checked

Answer (score 0):

```
samples = [[1,2], [1,4], [3,6], [3,8]]
key = 3
list(set([l for j in [i for i in samples if key in i] for l in j]))
# [8, 3, 6]
```

The `[i for i in samples if key in i]` creates the list of candidates. The rest is the flattening of the list and with `list(set(...))` you achieve that the sample are unique.

Answer (score 0):

just with list comprehension return a list of lists containing any of items you are looking for. then join (i found the sum method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)) these lists and make a set

```
def get_matches(matches, alist):
  return set(sum([y for x in matches for y in alist if(x in y)], []))

get_matches([1,4], [[1,2], [1,4], [3,6], [3,8]])
get_matches([3], [[1,2], [1,4], [3,6], [3,8]])
```