# Matching values within a dictionary and grouping elements to a new dictionary key

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, search

I have a dictionary which has the following form:

```
{ 1:['a','b'],
  2:['c','d'],
  3:['b','e'],
  4:['g','c'] 
..........
}
```

I want to find out if any values from the values matches with values in another key and then add it to another dictionary.In this example, in key 1 value 'b' matches with value 'b' in key 3. Si I want to group these together in a new dictionary for example

```
{100:['a','b''e']}.
```

Any suggestion on implementation or possible approaches preferably in Python would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where does `100` come from?

Comment: Maybe you can apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements

Comment: It would be new range of keys starting from 100.. Like { 100:['a','b''e'], 101:['c','d','g']}

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that key 103 would have a value of ['b', 'e', 'a'] ?

Answer (score 0):

how do you want to add it to a new dictionary the whole key or just the value to a new key? this is what I understood you want

```
dict = { 1:['a','b'],2:['c','d'],3:['b','e'],4:['g','c']}
matchs = {}
for key in dict:
    for key2 in dict:
        if key == key2:
            continue
        else:
            for value in dict[key]:
                if value in dict[key2]:
                    matchs[key] = key2



print(matchs)
```

OUTPUT: `{1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 2}`