# Python Pandas : Get unique records based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Before I start, I am not sure which terminology can I use, so I may misuse terms like "unique" and "duplicate".

Pandas dataset has three columns, A B and C. Rows are considered the same if they have either of the columns, A, B or C the same.
If we have this table:

| row num | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| 2 | A1 | B2 | C2 |
| 3 | A2 | B2 | C3 |
| 4 | A3 | B3 | C3 |

row 1 and 2 are the same because column A is the same, row 2 and 3 because of B, and row 3 and 4 because of C. This would mean that since 1 is duplicate of 2 which is duplicate of 3 which is duplicate of 4, I expect the number of unique records here is 1.

How would I write python pandas code to calculate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like graph problem (similar to this question: [Merge lists that share common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842613/merge-lists-that-share-common-elements))

Here is my take on the problem:

Initial dataframe (I will use index, not `row num`):

```py
   row num   A   B   C
0        1  A1  B1  C1
1        2  A1  B2  C2
2        3  A2  B2  C3
3        4  A3  B3  C3
4        5  A4  B4  C4
5        6  A5  B5  C5
6        7  A6  B4  C6
```

---

First we go for each column we want to investigate the duplicates:

```py
groups = []
for c in ["A", "B", "C"]:
    d = df.duplicated(subset=c, keep=False)
    groups.extend([set(g.index) for _, g in df.groupby(df.loc[d, c])])
```

This creates groups that need to be merged on common elements:

```py
[{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {4, 6}, {2, 3}]
```

Here we see that groups `{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}` share common elements and, group `{4, 6}` is separated. To compute that:

```py
out = []
while groups:
    g1 = groups.pop()
    while True:
        for g2 in groups:
            if g1 & g2:
                groups.remove(g2)
                g1 |= g2
                break
        else:
            out.append(g1)
            break
```

This creates `out`:

```py
[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 6}]
```

So there are 2 unique groups (= 2 unique values). But index `5` is missing:

```py
print(df.index.difference(set.union(*out)))
```

Prints:

```
Index([5], dtype='int64')
```

So the final number is `len(out)` + length of computed index

Comment: this seems to be an answer, as it has shown all correct answers for my sample dataset, only that it takes ages to execute on a bigger dataset. Thanks! I just need to wait

Comment: @Sale If speed is a problem, in the link I have in my answer there's accepted solution that uses `networkx` library (it should be faster than my computation of groups). You can give it a shot.

Comment: @Sale I add a link how to further speed up the `connected_components` method from `networkx` library: https://zpz.github.io/blog/connected-components/

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: with your new example, using [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/)

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A1', 'A7', 'A8'],
        'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B4', 'B4', 'B4', 'B4', 'B4'],
        'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9']}
dft = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
edges = pd.DataFrame(swv(dft[cols].values.ravel(), 2),
                     columns=['source', 'target'])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
uniq = nx.weakly_connected.number_weakly_connected_components(G)
```

Output:

```
>>> uniq
1

>>> edges
   source target
0      A1     B1
1      B1     C1
2      C1     A1
3      A1     B2
4      B2     C2
5      C2     A2
6      A2     B2
7      B2     C3
8      C3     A3
9      A3     B3
10     B3     C3
11     C3     A4
12     A4     B4
13     B4     C4
14     C4     A5
15     A5     B4
16     B4     C5
17     C5     A6
18     A6     B4
19     B4     C6
20     C6     A1
21     A1     B4
22     B4     C7
23     C7     A7
24     A7     B4
25     B4     C8
26     C8     A8
27     A8     B4
28     B4     C9
```

---

**Old answer**

You can use boolean masks:

```
m = pd.concat([df[col].duplicated() for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']], axis=1)

uniq = sum(~m.any(axis=1))  # number of unique rows

out = df[~m.any(axis=1)]  # you can also extract unique rows
```

Output:

```
>>> uniq
1

>>> m
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False  # never duplicated
1   True  False  False  # duplicated on A
2  False   True  False  # duplicated on B
3  False  False   True  # duplicated on C

>>> out
   row num   A   B   C
0        1  A1  B1  C1
```

Comment: Your solution is very fast, but I dont believe it would answer the issue. 

If I consider the following code:

    data = {'A': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
            'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B3'],
            'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3'],}
    
    dft = pd.DataFrame(data)
    dft.loc[4] = ['A4', 'B4', 'C4']
    dft.loc[5] = ['A5', 'B4', 'C5']
    dft.loc[6] = ['A6', 'B4', 'C6']
    dft.loc[7] = ['A1', 'B4', 'C7']
    dft.loc[8] = ['A7', 'B4', 'C8']
    dft.loc[9] = ['A8', 'B4', 'C9']`

It should again show only one row, but instead it shows 2 rows.

Comment: Your solution is very fast, but I dont believe it would answer the issue. 

If I consider the following code:
`data = {'A': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
            'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B2', 'B3'],
            'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3'],}`

`dft = pd.DataFrame(data)`
`dft.loc[4] = ['A4', 'B4', 'C4']`
`dft.loc[5] = ['A5', 'B4', 'C5']`
`dft.loc[6] = ['A6', 'B4', 'C6']`
`dft.loc[7] = ['A1', 'B4', 'C7']`
`dft.loc[8] = ['A7', 'B4', 'C8']`
`dft.loc[9] = ['A8', 'B4', 'C9']`

It should again show only one row, but instead it shows 2 rows.

Comment: @Sale. I don't understand. With your example, I have 2 rows (index 0 and 4) so `uniq` is 2. Check my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that is the key, there is connection between those two rows you made unique, row 7 and 0 is having A1 the same, so it now connects two groups into one. So the result would be 1 "unique" record.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I updated my answer.